# How to prevent context menu from closing when holding the Alt key?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

I need to allow the `Alt` key to be used as a modifier when selecting certain menu entries in a `ContextMenuStrip`. This works fine with all other modifiers like `Ctrl` or `Shift`. However, for some reason `Alt` automatically closes the context menu.

I tried using the `Closing` event in the context menu, and the menu item `AutoClose` property, but this is proving to be more clunky than anticipated. Specifically, even though the context menu is kept open, the application `MenuStrip` is activated (which may explain why the context menu closes in the first place).

I've tried searching around but I found surprisingly few questions about this, and none on stack overflow, so I wonder whether there might be a better way to work around this that I have missed?

Example code showing that suppressing `MenuStrip` activation does not prevent context menu from closing:

```
class MainForm : Form
{
    MenuStrip menuStrip;
    ContextMenuStrip contextMenuStrip;

    public MainForm()
    {
        KeyPreview = true;
        menuStrip = new MenuStrip();
        menuStrip.Items.Add("&File");
        Controls.Add(menuStrip);

        contextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
        contextMenuStrip.Items.Add("&OptionA");
        contextMenuStrip.Items.Add("&OptionB");
        ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip;
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Alt)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
        else base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: [WM_SYSKEYDOWN message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-syskeydown).

Comment: Care to elaborate? I cannot seem to intercept WM_SYSKEYDOWN on the `WndProc` method of the `ContextMenuStrip`, and in the other event overrides I am still not able to prevent this message from activating the `MenuStrip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design, so you'll have to do the state tracking yourself.  But this will definitely stop `Alt` from reaching the `MenuStrip`.

This is low level keyboard filtering, so you'll have to decide what to do when `Alt` is pressed entirely on your own, however.

You could also change the conditional to check for `Alt` *plus some state*.

In short, returning `true` from `PreFilterMesssage` will stop it from reaching your app.

```
static void Main()
{
    //...SNIP...
    Application.AddMessageFilter(new AltFilter());
    //...SNIP...
}

public class AltFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    private static ushort WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt)
        {
            //Do your own special thing instead
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. The problem is that I want `Alt` to function normally outside of the context menu. This is when these solutions become clunky, since I would need to exchange state between the context menu and the menu strip.

Comment: @glopes Then your best bet is to suppress `Alt` from hitting the `MenuStrip` when context menus are open.  You will still need to track state.  This can be done with `KeyPreview` turned on and handling it at the parent `Form` level with `KeyDown`.

Comment: Unfortunately, suppressing `Alt` with `KeyPreview` does not stop the context menu from closing. It does stop the `MenuStrip` itself from being activated, but the letters are still underlined, so somewhere it looks like there is some activation path that is still not entirely suppressed.

Comment: @glopes Can you post code that reproduces this?  The `Form` passes key presses onto children, in most cases.  Both work fine in very quick and dirty tests I whipped up.

Comment: done, it is strange, but something is definitely still stealing the focus from the context menu strip

Comment: @glopes I guess I'll get low level.  Here's a solution.  I'm aware it's not pretty.